# How can I connect the fields of two tables in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two models and for which I will create tables through migration and database update. My first model is named Service, and it consists of these fields:

```
public class Service
{
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }

    public string ServiceType { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string Subcategory { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

My second model is called Business, and it has the following fields:

```
public class Business
    {
        public int BusinessID { get; set; }

        public string BusinessName { get; set; }

        public string BusinessWebsite { get; set; }

        public string BusinessAddress { get; set; }

        public string BusinessCity { get; set; }

        public string BusinessState { get; set; }

        public string BusinessZip { get; set; }

        public string BusinessDescription { get; set; }

        [Range(0.0, 5.0)]
        public int Rating { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastLogIn { get; set; }

        // Need to add more fields
    }
```

The point is that I want to add Category and Subcategory fields into my Business model, but the values of Category and Subcategory fields, should be one of the values inside the Service table's values for Category and Subcategory.

Simply, I want to connect those two fields. How can I achieve it? Should I just put a Service property inside the Business model?

Comment: Are Service and (Category + SubCategory) a 1-1 mapping?

Comment: correct. There should be a Service Property with in Business if its 1:1 relationship. for 1:N, add  ICollection<Service>. if null value are accepted for Business.Service add Nullable<Service>. mark the property as virtual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break out a separate entity for "Category" and then use foreign keys:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    ...

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Subcategory { get; set; }
}

// Do the same when adding category/subcategory fields to `Business`
```

If you want to ensure that these categories are only tied to `Service` (and you potentially have other types of categories or something) you can always just make the entity `ServiceCategory` or something and only create a relationship to it from `Service`.

Comment: Should Category entity, be a separate model and table? Or, I can just specify it inside the Service.cs file?

Comment: Some clarification would help, I think. First, "entity" implies a database table backing it. Think "Entity Framework". That's where the name comes from. A "model" is a more abstract term, your entity *can* be a "model", but it's ultimately just a class. And, yes, it should be a separate class and entity (table in your database). Where you define it makes absolutely no difference. Your `.cs` files are just containers for code. Once your application compiles, it doesn't matter if it was written in 100 files or 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your break out your database to store lookup table for category and a lookup table for subcategory.

Then you can create:

```
public class Category {
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory {
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your service class to:

```
public class Service
{
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }

    public string ServiceType { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public int SubcategoryId { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and change your Business class to:

```
public class Business
{
    public int BusinessID { get; set; }

    public string BusinessName { get; set; }

    public string BusinessWebsite { get; set; }

    public string BusinessAddress { get; set; }

    public string BusinessCity { get; set; }

    public string BusinessState { get; set; }

    public string BusinessZip { get; set; }

    public string BusinessDescription { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }

    [Range(0.0, 5.0)]
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLogIn { get; set; }

    // Need to add more fields
}
```